# Is it possible to choose a specific log file(s) to display in ELK UI?

Tags: logging, kibana, devops, elastic-stack

There is something like this in Dynatrace UI ([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gelc6edltmin17o/Dynatryce%20-%20Logs%201.png?dl=0)) and I am trying to understand whether something like this is available in ELK. Or Sumologic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

- You could use filters, or query index patterns to get the specific logs, which could be the displayed in Kibana.